# Can I reuse argument instances to return values from aggregate functions in Spark?

Tags: apache-spark

I am wondering whether reusing objects is allowed in Spark in such case:

```
myRDD.aggregateByKey(DisplaysClicksSum.newZero(), (sum, displayClick) -> {
      sum.displaysSum += 1;
      sum.clicksSum += displayClick.clicked() ? 1 : 0;
      return sum;
    }, (sum1, sum2) -> {
      sum1.displaysSum += sum2.displaysSum;
      sum1.clicksSum += sum2.clicksSum;
      return sum1;
});
```

or should I create new objects to return them from these functions?

Comment: is `DisplaysClicksSum.zero()` creating a new instance every time? or are you trying to reuse a singleton object as the `sum` collector?

Comment: Good point, it returns of course new instance of DisplaysClicksSum object - I renamed it to newZero() in the snippet above to make it clear, Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is allowed, in the sense that nothing in Spark has a problem with it or forbids it. Just be sure that the initial value object is not being reused or changed by something else.

This can be a problem sometimes when using RDDs of `Writable` objects from Hadoop. Hadoop will reuse the objects from its `InputFormat` sometimes for performance, meaning it might be changing the values of these mutable objects underneath you, causing all kinds of surprise. That's not the case here though.